# Link click with Java & Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, hyperlink, webdriver

I've been trying for hours now to click a link with Selenium Webdriver in Java.

There are 6 links with different div IDs.

Here is the HTML code

```
<div id="aktion_tr1" class="aktion">
    <div class="zeile1">
    <a href="weiterleitung.php?id=1986070&amp;site_id=992307&amp;hash=f3684b9e9267d14823ca648b776f50a767532119" target="_blank" onclick="removeElement(&quot;aktion_tr1&quot;,2);"><img style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; max-height:70px;" src="/xxx/app/bilder/no-picture.gif" width="50px" border="0"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="zeile2">
    <a href="weiterleitung.php?id=1986070&amp;site_id=992307&amp;hash=f3684b9e9267d14823ca648b776f50a767532119" target="_blank" onclick="removeElement(&quot;aktion_tr1&quot;,2);">http://www.e-necker.at</a><br>Credits: 0.32 <img src="/xxx/app/bilder/credit20.jpg" align="absmiddle">
    </div>
    </div><div id="aktion_tr2" class="aktion">
    <div class="zeile1">
    <a href="weiterleitung.php?id=1986070&amp;site_id=1162375&amp;hash=4ad08bd29eb0974ccad030ed20f05554e6fbe74f" target="_blank" onclick="removeElement(&quot;aktion_tr2&quot;,2);"><img style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; max-height:70px;" src="/xxx/app/bilder/no-picture.gif" width="50px" border="0"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="zeile2">
    <a href="weiterleitung.php?id=1986070&amp;site_id=1162375&amp;hash=4ad08bd29eb0974ccad030ed20f05554e6fbe74f" target="_blank" onclick="removeElement(&quot;aktion_tr2&quot;,2);">http://midineroganadopromos.blogspot....</a><br>Credits: 0.16 <img src="/xxx/app/bilder/credit20.jpg" align="absmiddle">
    </div>
    </div><div id="aktion_tr3" class="aktion">
    <div class="zeile1">
    <a href="weiterleitung.php?id=1986070&amp;site_id=1288317&amp;hash=ab8e3b3b694850e7e63bb7f6ea91f86f69cc269a" target="_blank" onclick="removeElement(&quot;aktion_tr3&quot;,2);"><img style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; max-height:70px;" src="/xxx/app/bilder/no-picture.gif" width="50px" border="0"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="zeile2">
    <a href="weiterleitung.php?id=1986070&amp;site_id=1288317&amp;hash=ab8e3b3b694850e7e63bb7f6ea91f86f69cc269a" target="_blank" onclick="removeElement(&quot;aktion_tr3&quot;,2);">https://www.haar-pigmentierung.com</a><br>Credits: 0.27 <img src="/xxx/app/bilder/credit20.jpg" align="absmiddle">
    </div>
    </div><div id="aktion_tr4" class="aktion">
    <div class="zeile1">
    <a href="weiterleitung.php?id=1986070&amp;site_id=1313235&amp;hash=c9f372e535b2e8cfe567b10b016f5130189690eb" target="_blank" onclick="removeElement(&quot;aktion_tr4&quot;,2);"><img style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; max-height:70px;" src="/xxx/app/bilder/no-picture.gif" width="50px" border="0"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="zeile2">
    <a href="weiterleitung.php?id=1986070&amp;site_id=1313235&amp;hash=c9f372e535b2e8cfe567b10b016f5130189690eb" target="_blank" onclick="removeElement(&quot;aktion_tr4&quot;,2);">https://www.tierreich-onlineshop.at</a><br>Credits: 0.27 <img src="/xxx/app/bilder/credit20.jpg" align="absmiddle">
    </div>
    </div><div id="aktion_tr5" class="aktion">
    <div class="zeile1">
    <a href="weiterleitung.php?id=1986070&amp;site_id=1316482&amp;hash=a64ebbe58790e53d1b7fd931d6b74d87667eb9c6" target="_blank" onclick="removeElement(&quot;aktion_tr5&quot;,2);"><img style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; max-height:70px;" src="/xxx/app/bilder/no-picture.gif" width="50px" border="0"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="zeile2">
    <a href="weiterleitung.php?id=1986070&amp;site_id=1316482&amp;hash=a64ebbe58790e53d1b7fd931d6b74d87667eb9c6" target="_blank" onclick="removeElement(&quot;aktion_tr5&quot;,2);">https://www.loluva.com</a><br>Credits: 0.27 <img src="/xxx/app/bilder/credit20.jpg" align="absmiddle">
    </div>
    </div><div id="aktion_tr6" class="aktion">
    <div class="zeile1">
    <a href="weiterleitung.php?id=1986070&amp;site_id=1322064&amp;hash=99fbad1b8adaf3b6f93cbc01e8e71a5bb2ebc4bf" target="_blank" onclick="removeElement(&quot;aktion_tr6&quot;,2);"><img style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; max-height:70px;" src="/xxx/app/bilder/no-picture.gif" width="50px" border="0"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="zeile2">
    <a href="weiterleitung.php?id=1986070&amp;site_id=1322064&amp;hash=99fbad1b8adaf3b6f93cbc01e8e71a5bb2ebc4bf" target="_blank" onclick="removeElement(&quot;aktion_tr6&quot;,2);">https://www.main-steam.de/</a><br>Credits: 0.32 <img src="/xxx/app/bilder/credit20.jpg" align="absmiddle">
    </div>
    </div><div style="clear:both"></div>
```

How i can navigate to the links?

thanks for your time

Comment: So what is your requirement? Which link(s) are you trying to click?

Answer (score 0):

```
// get parrent div    
WebElement divAktion_tr1 = driver.findElement(By.id("aktion_tr1"));

// get all childs a tags
ArrayList<WebElement> aHrefs = divAktion_tr1.findElements(By.tagname("a"));

// declare desired link id or any part of the href or whole href
String linkId1 = "1986070";

// loop child a tags
for (WebElement aHref: aHrefs) {

    // get href attribute       
    String href = aHref.getAttribute("href");

    // condition to pinpoint desired link, maybe need use CharSequence instead of String to use Objects.containts(Object)       
    if (href.contains(linkId1) {

        // click         
        aHref.click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what exactly you're trying to achieve but, in general, you're just instantiate WebElement object with a css/xpath locator that leads to the link you need and call `click()` on it

```
WebDriver link1 = driver.findElement(By.css("#aktion_tr6 .zeile2 a"));   // CSS
WebDriver link2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='aktion_tr4']/div[@class="zeile2"]/a")); // XPATH

link1.click();
link2.click();
```